# Sculpt for glasses nosepads

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I have a glasses model :

[image]

**But, how I can make nosepad like this:**

[image]

I tried Sculpt mode, but i cant.

Thanks

Comment: From the first image in your question, the glasses are probably done from some svg or similar approach. You should model it instead, so that the surround for each eye is a face loop (a suite of quad faces). Once done, you can extrude or inset the nosepad easily. But sculpting is probably not the good approach anyway for that.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the basic shape of the eyeglass frame. 
I started with a circle with 64 vertices and formed that to the inside of the frame and then extruded that out and shaped the outside of the frame. 
[image: Eyeglass shape]

Then extruded that shape up to create the thickness of the frame. (I also used a Mirror Modifier and a Sub Surf Modifier).
[image: Eyeglass Depth]

I then selected the vertices that would make up the nose piece and pressed CTRL + “I” to inverse the selection. Then pressed “H” to hide that.
[image: Selected Vertices]

Then selected the following eight vertices and turned on Proportional Editing “Connected” choose “Sharp” for the falloff and pressed “G” and moved them up.
[image: Selected eight vertices]
[image]

Then changed the falloff to “Linear” pressed "S" and scaled them in. 
[image]

You can press ALT + “H” to unhide the rest of the vertices and/or Tab into Object Mode to see the result.
[image: Result]
[image: Result Object]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use *proportional editing* with the *X mirror* option on,
then move vertices to the desired location.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1kCn0yQrtY